# Solve ODE using Laplace: $(y''' - y) = ye^{2t}$

Tags: laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I am trying to solve
$$
y''' - y = -ye^{2t}.
$$
with initial values $y(0) = 0$, $y'(0) = -1$, $y''(0) = -3$

The problem I am running in to is when I am transforming the left and right side of the equation:
$$
L{y'''} - L{y} = - L{ye^{2t}}
$$
Using rules for transformation I get:
$$
Y(s)s^3 + 3s^2 +s - Y(s) = Y(s-2). 
$$
Normally one would just solve for Y and do the inverse Laplace transform. However, now the right hand side is **S-shifted**.

Is there a general method for solving this, or any tricks one might apply to get rid of the **S-shift** or $e^{2t}$ term from the original equation?

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in the DE  because even without Laplace Method the DE has no solution with elementary functions

Comment: Maybe you can do substitution and identify a hyperbolic function.

Comment: hum  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=y%27%27%27+-+y+%3D+-y%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29Power%5Be%2C%5C%2840%292t%5C%2841%29%5D